# Hadoop Mapper parameters explaination

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I'm new to **Hadoop**, and are confused with [Mapper](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) parameters.

Take the well known *WordCount* as sample:

```
class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
  private Text outputKey;
  private IntWritable outputVal;

  @Override
  public void setup(Context context) {
    outputKey = new Text();
    outputVal = new IntWritable(1);
  }

  @Override
  public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
    while(stk.hasMoreTokens()) {
      outputKey.set(stk.nextToken());
      context.write(outputKey, outputVal);
    }
  }
}
```

See `map` function, the parameters are `Object key`, `Text value` and `Context context`, I'm confused about what the `Object key` looks like (you see, `key` is never used in `Map` function).

Since the input file format is like:

```
Deer
Beer
Bear
Beer
Deer
Deer
Bear
...
```

I know ***value*** looks like each line `Deer`, `Beer`, and so on. They are processed line by line.

But how is ***key*** looks like? How to decide which data type ***key*** should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything here depends on your `InputFormat` class used. It parses input data source and provides you with (Key, Value) pairs. Different input format implementations can provide you with different stream even having the same input source.

Here is article which demonstrates approach:

https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/custom-recordreader-processing-string-pattern-delimited-records/

Main driver here is `RecordReader`.

Comment: Hello, the link is broken, could you help take a look?

Comment: Added different illustration. It is not so hard to find them if you know what to search.